# How to disable custom function re-run after opening a sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a custom function like this:

```
  var today = new Date();
  var date = (today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate()+'-'+today.getFullYear();
  var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
  var dateTime = date+' '+time;
  return dateTime;
```

And I call the function above in the cells in Google Sheet. But everytime I open the sheet, all the function re-run and get a new timestamp. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Depending on your condition to generate a one-time date for a cell, you will most likely need to use the [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilise the `Sheet.getCurrentCell()` method to check if the cell already has a value and return it back if it does:

```
function getTimestamp() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const cell = ss.getActiveSheet().getCurrentCell()
  
  if (cell.getDisplayValue() !== "" && cell.getDisplayValue() !== "Loading...") {
    return cell.getDisplayValue()
  }
  
  var today = new Date()
  var date = (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate() + '-' + today.getFullYear()
  var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds()
  var dateTime = date + ' ' + time
  return dateTime
}
```

As per the [documentation on Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_apps_script_services):

> Custom functions can call certain Apps Script services to perform more complex tasks.

and:

> [Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet) | Read only (can use most `get*()` methods, but not `set*()`).

So the idea is thus:

- Get the active Spreadsheet
- Get the current cell
- Check to see if the current cell has a value
- If it does, return that value (ie do not recalculate) *unless* that value is 'Loading...' (the function takes a moment to calculate during which the cell reads 'Loading...')
- If it does not, calculate the timestamp and set it